# WooCommerce variable price to show default value

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to show in my store the price set for each varying product by default. It currently shows me the highest price of product variations and I can't find a way to change it.

I have high price there and this code in loop start page:

```
<h5 class="network-price"><?php echo get_field('network_price_text',$p_id); ?> <?php echo $currency;  echo $variation_product->regular_price; ?>pm</h5>
<h5 class="our-price"><?php echo get_field('our_price_text',$p_id); ?> : <?php echo $currency; echo $variation_product->sale_price; ?>pm</h5>
```

Would you be able to help me with solution?

Comment: If you want to see my solution please visit this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101365/woocommerce-default-variation-display-price/70101854#70101854

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need to select the basic product variation, like you have three prices like 20$, 30$ and 40$. Then select the basic variation product it helps to show your least amount of the product.

Also, here is some helpful code:

```
$variation_min_price = $product->get_variation_price();
```

Comment: Where should I put the code?

Comment: I found this one but doesn’t work for me:

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'get_min_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'get_min_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

function get_min_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
    $min_variation_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min');
    return wc_price($min_variation_price);
}

Comment: I found a solution Areeb. Thank you!

Comment: @Davy you are welcome. Also, please share the solution here so it helps others. :)