# WooCommerce default variation display price

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to change something here to show default variation price on my store page:

```html
<div class="deal-part2-details">
<?php
if($product->get_type() == "simple"){
?>
    <h5><?php echo get_field('network_price_text',$p_id); ?> <?php echo $currency;  echo $product->regular_price; ?>pm</h5>
    <h5 class="our-price"><?php echo get_field('our_price_text',$p_id); ?> : <?php echo $currency; echo $product->sale_price; ?>pm</h5>
    <h6><?php echo get_field('upfront_cost',$p_id); ?> <?php echo get_field('upfront_cost_text',$p_id); ?></h6>
        <?php
            }else{
            $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            $variation_product_id = $product_variations [0]['variation_id'];
            $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_product_id );
                                                    
        ?>
    <h5 class="network-price"><?php echo get_field('network_price_text',$p_id); ?> <?php echo $currency;  echo $variation_product->regular_price; ?>pm</h5>
    <h5 class="our-price"><?php echo get_field('our_price_text',$p_id); ?> : <?php echo $currency; echo $variation_product->sale_price; ?>pm</h5>
                                                    
<!--<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
<span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?> -->
                                                    
<h6><?php echo get_field('upfront_cost',$p_id); ?><?php echo get_field('upfront_cost_text',$p_id); ?></h6>
<?php
                }
        ?>
</div>
```

Would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just change code like that, and working for me:

```html
<div class="deal-part2-details">
<?php
if($product->get_type() == "simple"){
?>
    <h5><?php echo get_field('network_price_text',$p_id); ?> <?php echo $currency;  echo $product->regular_price; ?>pm</h5>
    <h5 class="our-price"><?php echo get_field('our_price_text',$p_id); ?> : <?php echo $currency; echo $product->sale_price; ?>pm</h5>
    <h6><?php echo get_field('upfront_cost',$p_id); ?> <?php echo get_field('upfront_cost_text',$p_id); ?></h6>
        <?php
            }else{
            $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            $variation_product_id = $product_variations [0]['variation_id'];
            $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_product_id );
            $price_regular_min = $product->get_variation_regular_price();
            $price_sale_min = $product->get_variation_sale_price();
        ?>
    <h5 class="network-price"><?php echo get_field('network_price_text',$p_id); ?> <?php echo $currency;  echo $price_regular_min; ?>pm</h5>
    <h5 class="our-price"><?php echo get_field('our_price_text',$p_id); ?> : <?php echo $currency; echo $price_sale_min; ?>pm</h5>
                                                    
<!--<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
<span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?> -->
                                                    
<h6><?php echo get_field('upfront_cost',$p_id); ?><?php echo get_field('upfront_cost_text',$p_id); ?></h6>
<?php
                }
        ?>
</div>
```

For that point I just add two variable:

```html
$price_regular_min = $product->get_variation_regular_price();
$price_sale_min = $product->get_variation_sale_price();
```

And then I activated them here:

```html
<h5 class="network-price"><?php echo get_field('network_price_text',$p_id); ?> <?php echo $currency; echo $price_regular_min; ?>pm</h5>
<h5 class="our-price"><?php echo get_field('our_price_text',$p_id); ?> : <?php echo $currency; echo $price_sale_min; ?>pm</h5>
```

I made these changes in my loop-start.php
This is my simple solution and working pretty well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

**Step1:**
1st you can edit variable product & select variation values. Which variation
you want shown on product page **Default Form Values** See the screenshot [Select Default value screenshot](https://prnt.sc/2175seo)

**Step:2**
Then go to your active theme or child theme `functions.php` file put below code.

```
//woo_default_price_variation_price

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'woo_default_price_variation_price', 10, 2);

function woo_default_price_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $pav){
    $def=true;
    foreach($product->get_variation_default_attributes() as $defkey=>$defval){
       if($pav['attributes']['attribute_'.$defkey]!=$defval){
          $def=false; 
    }
}
      if($def){
          $price = $pav['display_price']; 
      }
  } 
  return woocommerce_price($price);
}
```

It's 100% working

Thanks